# synchronizing XML nodes between class and file using C#

Tags: c#, xml, file-io, xml-serialization, abstraction

I'm trying to write an `IXmlSerializable` class that stays synced with an XML file.  The XML file has the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <logging>
    <logLevel>Error</logLevel>
  </logging>
  ...potentially other sections...
</configuration>
```

I have a `DllConfig` class for the whole XML file and a `LoggingSection` class for representing `<logging>` and its contents, i.e., `<logLevel>`.  `DllConfig` has this property:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = LOGGING_TAG_NAME,
    DataType = "LoggingSection")]
public LoggingSection Logging { get; protected set; }
```

What I want is for the backing XML file to be updated (i.e., rewritten) when a property is set.  I already have `DllConfig` do this when `Logging` is set.  However, how should I go about doing this when `Logging.LogLevel` is set?  Here's an example of what I mean:

```
var config = new DllConfig("path_to_backing_file.xml");
config.Logging.LogLevel = LogLevel.Information; // not using Logging setter, but a
                                                // setter on LoggingSection, so how
                                                // does path_to_backing_file.xml
                                                // have its contents updated?
```

My current solution is to have a `SyncedLoggingSection` class that inherits from `LoggingSection` and also takes a `DllConfig` instance in the constructor.  It declares a `new LogLevel` that, when set, updates the `LogLevel` in the base class and also uses the given `DllConfig` to write the entire `DllConfig` out to the backing XML file.  Is this a good technique?

I don't think I can just serialize `SyncedLoggingSection` by itself to the backing XML file, because not all of the contents will be written, just the `<logging>` node.  Then I'd end up with an XML file containing only the `<logging>` section with its updated `<logLevel>`, instead of the entire config file with `<logLevel>` updated.  Hence, I need to pass an instance of `DllConfig` to `SyncedLoggingSection`.

It seems almost like I want an event handler, one in `DllConfig` that would notice when particular properties (i.e., `LogLevel`) in its properties (i.e., `Logging`) were set.  Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Sarah, is there a reason you aren't just using the standard types in the `System.Configuration` namespace?

Comment: @John:  are you referring to using app.config with an automagical Config.settings in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm talking about creating custom configuration sections that can be used in app.config or web.config, as appropriate. You can use standard mechanisms to write changes back to the file. See the [ConfigurationManager class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are implementing IXmlSerializable yourself, you can make DllConfig.Logging private. Then add a public method on DllConfig to set LogLevel instead of setting Logging.LogLevel directly. That will be the only way you can change the LogLevel. In the implementation of that public method, you can serialize the whole DllConfig to overwrite the xml.